# What is the Type?

Tags: c#, types

I have a issue to define the `Type` in my code. Let's start from Abc.

```
public partial class Abc {
    public static String AbcName="wtf";

    public String Name {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Okay, ***`Abc` is done***. It's a class for test afterwards. And I have the requirment to return objects or types with a instance of `MyClass`, here it is

```
    public partial class MyClass {
        public const BindingFlags
            Universal=BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Public,
            WithObject=Universal|BindingFlags.Instance,
            WithClass=WithObject|BindingFlags.Static,
            ForGive=Universal|BindingFlags.SetProperty|BindingFlags.SetField,
            ForGet=Universal|BindingFlags.GetProperty|BindingFlags.GetField,
            ForDo=BindingFlags.InvokeMethod|WithObject|WithClass;

        public MyClass GetTypeImpl() {
            if(null!=target)
#if TARGET_AS_TYPE
                return new MyClass(target as Type??target.GetType());
#else
                return new MyClass(target.GetType());
#endif
            else
                return new MyClass(typeof(object));
        }

        public object GetValue(String name) {
            var invokeAttr=ForGet|WithClass;
            var type=(Type)this.GetTypeImpl().target;
            return type.InvokeMember(name, invokeAttr, default(Binder), target, default(object[]));
        }

        public MyClass(object x) {
            this.target=x;
        }

        public object target;
    }
```

Notice that the code is for representing of my class. `GetValue` in real code is called internally, and consuming code will never get a object other than the type of `MyClass`. That is, ***in the real code, every method in `MyClass` is actually return a instance of `MyClass`***. 
Here we see the conditional compilation, with `TARGET_AS_TYPE`, that is the point of this question.

Consider the following test code

```
    public partial class TestClass {
        public static void TestMethod() {
            var abc=
                new Abc {
                    Name="xyz"
                };

            var x=new MyClass(abc);
            var abcName=x.GetValue("Name");
            var y=new MyClass(x.GetTypeImpl().target);

#if TARGET_AS_TYPE
            var wtf=y.GetValue("AbcName");
            var fullName=y.GetValue("FullName"); // exception thrown
#else
            var fullName=y.GetValue("FullName"); 
            var wtf=y.GetValue("AbcName"); // exception thrown
#endif
        }
    }
```

Whether we define `TARGET_AS_TYPE` or not, ***the test always throws exception with the second line with `#if` or `#elseif` block***. 
I think it is because of the `Type` or `RuntimeType`, but I cannot define it. 
So, ***how to correct it(in GetTypeImpl) and let it always work without conditional compilation***?

Following ways are restricted or I've done with no effect.

- use of `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` - not working
- declaration of generic `MyClass<T>` - not working
- don't warp types or objects with instance of `MyClass` - you must be kidding me ...

Comment: An exception is thrown there, because `y` represents the `Type` object, which does not contain `AbcName`. To access it you should use `x` probably. However try to think what line `var y=new MyClass(x.GetTypeImpl().target);` does...at the very least it creates an unnecessary instance of `MyClass` within `GetTypeImpl` method...while `y` in the end appears to be a `MyClass` wrapper around `MyClass` which is a wrapper around the `Type` object.

Comment: may help to post the exception being thrown.

Comment: Is `GetValue` supposed to return the value of a property of the wrapped object or the wrapped object's type?  You're using it for both in your example ("AbcName" is on `Abc` and "FullName" is on `Type`)...

Comment: You are specifying the target in `InvokeMember` even if you are trying to retrieve static field value. I think that this makes a problem and that you must pass `null` in that situation!

Comment: @KenKin You seem to mix the `Type` object of an object, which describes its type and the object itself. Your code seems to wrap around an object and return any of its properties (fields, whatever)...but you cannot access both `Type` and `MyClass` members from one object. You need to distinguish them.

Comment: @Ken Kin: You misunderstood... you MUST specify `null` for the target in `InvokeMember` if you are trying to get a value from `AbcName`... that is making you a problem

Comment: @Ken Kin: why are you creating instance of MyClass in GetTypeImpl instead of just returning type of target???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
Abc a = new Abc { Name = "a" };

Type t = a.GetType();

BindingFlags staticField = BindingFlags.Static | 
                           BindingFlags.Public | 
                           BindingFlags.GetField;
BindingFlags instanceProperty = BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                BindingFlags.Public | 
                                BindingFlags.GetProperty;

//prints a
t.InvokeMember("Name", instanceProperty, default(Binder), a, null);
//prints wtf
t.InvokeMember("AbcName", staticField, default(Binder), a, null);
//throws an exception as there is no member FullName in MyClass
t.InvokeMember("FullName", instanceProperty, default(Binder), a, null);

Type tt = t.GetType();
//prints t.FullName, that is YourNamespace.Abc
tt.InvokeMember("FullName", instanceProperty, default(Binder), t, null);
```

It shows the problem, that you IMO have. You cannot access members of class `Type` through an object of type `Type` describing class `MyClass` via reflection, as `MyClass` does not have those members.

You need to use the `Type` object describing class `Type` (i.e. `a.GetType().GetType()`) to access its members (`FullName` here) through reflection and pass an object of type `Type` describing class `MyClass` to `InvokeMember`.

---

Based on comments, I'd like to post the same example over an object of type `System.Object`:

```
object o = new object();
Type ot = o.GetType();

BindingFlags instanceMethod = BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                BindingFlags.Public | 
                                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod;

//prints System.Object
ot.InvokeMember("ToString", instanceMethod, default(Binder), o, null);
//throws an exception, 
//as there is obviously also no FullName in class System.Object
ot.InvokeMember("FullName", instanceProperty, default(Binder), o, null);
```

Comment: @KenKin There isn't any way to, I guess. `MyClass` and `Type` are two separate objects, so they have absolutely separate `Type` objects describing them. You cannot union these two infos into one object. Except, probably searching for all the members within `a.GetType()` and if nothing has been found, search for the member in `a.GetType().GetType()`.

Comment: @KenKin it's just absolutely the same with `System.Object`.